# Best data mining algorithm for detect the profile of students with excellent grades

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics, data-mining

I have a dataset of students profiles (Age,sex,address...etc) with the performance note (1 the worst, 5 the best). 
I would like to know what could be the best data mining algorithm to determine the profile of those students with a performance bigger than 4.
Until the moment, I have think in clustering algorithm (K-means...) bus these are unsupervised algorithms so it's difficult for to fix a cluster with 100% of probability of having a student with the performance wished. Do you have any suggestion? Is there a better algorithm to achieve the objectives? Thanks!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.  Could you post an example of the code you already have so we can begin where you are already?

Comment: Since you already have the performance notes, why do you need any algorithm?

Comment: Because based on the notes I would love to know a predictive probability of the profile values for the students with good notes. Somebody already gave me a good alternative. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not sound like a clustering problem to me.

Instead, you are looking for a decision tree, on the target variable "grade > 4".

Answer (score 0):

Decision trees, Neural network, SVD can be applied to characterize high performance students. There is no guarantees of perfect classification. You can see the quality of the model based on the accuracy measures.